# Inconsistent behavior between Scala tail recursion vs imperative

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I'm currently attempting to learn functional programming (and Scala) together. I'm porting some code from a FORTRAN routine for calculating a particular modified normalisation of the associated Legendre polynomials. My direct imperative translation of the original code is modpLgndr1 (which I have checked against the original algorithm). My initial attempt at writing the code in a functional form is in modpLgdnr2.

```
import math.pow, abs, sqrt, Pi

def xfact(m: Int): Double = {
  if (m <= 1) 1.0
  else {
    if (m % 2 == 1) m.toDouble / sqrt(m.toDouble) * xfact(m - 1)
    else 1.0 / sqrt(m.toDouble) * xfact(m - 1)
  }
}

//this is a very un-scala function....
def modpLgndr1(l: Int, m: Int, x: Double): Double = {
  assert(0 <= m && m <= l && abs(x) <= 1.0)
  val dl = l.toDouble
  val dm = m.toDouble
  val norm = sqrt(2.0 * dl + 1.0) / sqrt(4.0 * Pi)
  var pmm = norm
  if (m != 0) pmm = (pow(-1, m)).toDouble * pmm * xfact(2 * m) * pow((1.0-x * x), (dm / 2.0))
  if (l == m) pmm
  else {
    var pmmp1 = x * pmm * sqrt(2.0 * m + 1.0)
    if (l == m + 1) pmmp1
    else {
      var pll = 0.0
      var dll = 0.0
      for (ll <- m + 2 to l) {
        dll = ll.toDouble
        pll = (x * (2.0 * dll - 1.0) * pmmp1 - sqrt(pow((dll - 1.0), 2.0) - dm * dm) * pmm) / sqrt(pow(dll, 2.0) - pow(dm, 2.0))
        pmm = pmmp1
        pmmp1 = pll
      }
      pll
    }
  }
}

def modpLgndr2(l: Int, m: Int, x: Double): Double = {
  assert(0 <= m && m <= l && abs(x) <= 1.0)
  val dl = l.toDouble
  val dm = m.toDouble
  val norm = sqrt(2.0 * dl + 1.0) / sqrt(4.0 * Pi)
  val pmm = if (m == 0) norm else (pow(-1, m)).toDouble * norm * xfact(2 * m) * pow((1.0-x * x), (dm / 2.0))
  if (l == m) pmm
  else {
    val pmmp1 = x * pmm * sqrt(2.0 * m + 1.0)
    if (l == m + 1) pmmp1
    else {
      def mplacc(ll: Int, acc1: Double, acc2: Double): Double = {
        val dll = ll.toDouble
        val pll = (x * (2.0 * dll - 1.0) * acc2 - sqrt(pow((dll - 1.0), 2.0) - dm * dm) * acc1) / sqrt(pow(dll, 2.0) - pow(dm, 2.0))
        if (ll == m + 2) pll
        else mplacc(ll - 1, acc2, pll)
      }
      mplacc(l, pmm, pmmp1)
    }
  }
}
```

If I call the two functions I get output like this:

```
scala> for (i <- 0 to 10) println(modpLgndr1(10,i,0.2))
```

0.16685408398957746
-0.2769345073769805
-0.1575129272628402
0.2948210515201088
0.12578847877176355
-0.3292975894931367
-0.058267280378036426
0.37448134558730417
-0.08024600262585084
-0.40389602261165075
0.4424459249420354

```
scala> for (i <- 0 to 10) println(modpLgndr2(10,i,0.2))
```

0.16685408398957752
-0.2772969351441124
-0.1578618478786792
0.29654926805696474
0.1349402872678466
-0.33707342609134694
-0.06901634276825179
0.38912154672892657
-0.08024600262585084
-0.40389602261165075
0.4424459249420354

Essentially, for m = 0, l-2, l-1, l the code agrees; otherwise there is a significant discrepancy. That seems to tell me that the problem is in calling the mplacc function. To me, mplacc just looks like a recursive form of the for loop in modpLgndr1. Why am I wrong?

Comment: I wonder if you're accumulating rounding errors differently

Comment: I aggree with @Daenyth. Looks like your first code, you accumulate from  m+2 to l and in the second one, from l to m-2.Floating point additions are definitely not associative. I expect that if you change the first loop to go down (l to (m+2) by -1) you will get the same on both side. Anyway it seems that your calculation is very sensitive to rounding errors.

Comment: Yeah I read a similar post about floating point rounding errors affecting another scala neophyte, but theirs were in the 15th decimal place or something like that! I will check it out.